# Spring CommandLineRunner doesn't run with WAR classes dependency

Tags: java, spring, maven, war

So I am trying to import the classes from a local project that is built into a war project. However when adding this dependency to maven it no longer runs the Spring CommandLineRunner `run` function.

The example war dependency that breaks the code:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.company<groupId>
   <artifactId>artifact<artifactId>
   <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT<version>
   <classifier>classes<classifier>
<dependency>
```

The Java code that isn't run:

```java
public class App implements CommandLineRunner
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
        new SpringApplication(App.class).run(App.class, args);
    }

       @Override
       public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
             System.out.println("HELLO WORLD");
       }
}
```

So, when the above maven dependency is added it shows the Spring banner but then doesn't show any other output below it.

Comment: If it doesn't exit then it's possible your company's war has reconfigured the logging and your application is still running. Have any mysterious log files been created (e.g. catalina.log?)

Comment: Yes, there are a few INFO statements before the banner with stuff about logging, but do not see any catalina.log file. Also, a thing to note is that I am compiling my code into a jar and running via command line.

Comment: Does your process exit or stay alive with no logging? If it's alive are you able to call it through its usual REST port?

Comment: So, actually, I was not using it for anything pertaining to REST, just wanted to create a commandline SpringBoot application that will just run, execute code, and then exit similar to a normal Java application but importing Spring classes from that war file. So currently when it doesn't run correctly, it completes execution immediately after the Spring banner.

Comment: if it doesn't exit, launch a thread dump with jstack and then post the stacktrace. spring boot heavily manifest and classpath scanning... is there something in classes/exploded jar you import ?